# Printing a simple linked list in C++, data-structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I have problems printing a singly linked list,it must look for example so:
[1:2][3:4][7:2][9:1], but the result/the output is without the last element, i.e. so:  [1:2][3:4][7:2]. This is my data-structure:

```
struct numbers {
int info1;
int info2;   
numbers *next; 
};

struct numbers* next= NULL; //At first 0,because the list is empty
struct numbers* head=NULL;  //at the beginning
```

And the function,that I call later:

```
void printing(numbers *head) { 
numbers *temp=head;
if(head!=NULL) {
    do {
        printf("[%d:%d]",temp->info1, temp->info2);
        temp=temp->next;
    }   while(temp->next!=head && temp->next!=0);
}   
    return;
}
```

Is there a mistake in this function?

Comment: `head!=NULL` should be `temp!=NULL`

Comment: while(temp!=head && temp!=0);

Comment: temp->next!=0 should be temp!=NULL

Comment: If you only want to store 2 int values per entry, simply use a std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >, this will handle all these problems for you.

Comment: @Diana Papukchieva I see that most of your questions are devoted to linked lists. Are you specializing on linked list? You will be a guru on linked lists!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the condition

```
temp->next!=head
```

The last node is not outputed because instead of

```
temp->next!=0
```

you have to check

```
temp != 0
```

because you already moved the pointer inside the loop

```
temp=temp->next;
```

So the function is wrong. It should look like

```
void printing( numbers *head ) 
{ 
    for ( numbers *temp = head; temp != 0; temp = temp->next )
    {
        printf( "[%d:%d]", temp->info1, temp->info2 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `while` condition, I don't know why you are checking for `temp->next!=head`.

But for null condition, you should be checking `temp!=0` or `temp!=NULL` instead of `temp->next!=0`

Answer (score 1):

Just this code is enough . The problem with your code is that you return when ever it's next pointer become NULL , that's the case for last node .

```
void printing(numbers *head) { 
  numbers *temp=head;
  while( temp != NULL ){
        printf("[%d:%d]",temp->info1, temp->info2);
        temp=temp->next;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the hepp and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are advancing to the next node and then you are checking if that node has an empty next node.  Because of this you will never print the last node.  You can rewrite your code to:

```
void printing(numbers *head) {
    numbers *temp = head;
    if (head != NULL) {
        while (temp != NULL)
            printf("[%d:%d]", temp->info1, temp->info2);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```